# How to convert exponential value to string format in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing some calculations which give very small decimal numbers for example, `0.0000082`

When I'm saving it in a variable, it changes into exponent form. I need the result as a string in the end. So, converting the result using `str()` is not possible because it keeps the `e` in the string.
I need the string to have exactly 8 decimal places. Is there any way to do this while keeping the 8 digit precision intact?

Another example: `5.8e-06` should be converted to `'0.00000580'` The trailing zero in the final string is not important.
I need the string to be used elsewhere. So, this shouldn't be done in the `print()` function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exponential notation is not an inherent property of the number (which is stored as a binary floating point value). It's just the default representation when converting the number to a string with `str`. You can specify your own formatting options if you convert the number to a string using the `format` function. Try something like this:

```
format(5.8e-06, '.8f')
```

The `8` in the format specifier tells it to use eight digits of precision, while the `f` requests it to be written as a plain decimal without exponential notation. You can read more about the format notations [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. It gives much more insight. I will accept this answer.

Answer (score 5):

Just another idea:

```
'{0:.7f}'.format(0.0000082)
```

Answer (score 3):

you can try with :

```
import decimal

print(str(decimal.Decimal(5.8e-06))[:10])

>>> 0.00000580
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Comment: i'm just looking for a better slicing.. wait a sec

Comment: Yes, the integer part will not be preserved by this method.

Answer (score 3):

```
print ("{:.6f}".format(1e-4))
```

will print out

```
0.000100
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use print:

```
>>> number = 1e-08
>>> number
1e-08
>>>print("{:.12f}".format(float(number)))
0.000000010000
```

or You could convert number and store it in string:

```
>>> str1 = "{:.12f}".format(float(number))
>>> str1
'0.000000010000'
```